# adding main class into the manifest file

Tags: java, jar

I created a jar file like this :

```
jar cf myJAR.jar *.class
```

But this thing is not executable because the mainfest file does not know in which `.class` file is the main file ?

Now how can i set the main class into the manifest file ?

Answer (score 2):

The manifest file must include the following line

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

In JDK6 there is a commandline parameter to add it automatically

```
jar cfe Main.jar foo.Main foo/Main.class
```

foo is the package in this example. The second example creates the manifest automatically.

Comment: so i will add the `main class` after i create the manifest file ?

Comment: No you create your classes with javac and then you put an additional file the so called `manifest` inside your jar and this file hold this line.

Comment: Isn't there a method that main class is known to the manifest file as soon as the manifest file is created ?

Comment: You may have multiple classes inside the jar containing a main method. I edit my post just a second.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple classes having THE `main` method ?

Comment: not "THE" main method. There is no such thing like The main method. You may have multiple entrypoints in your application the so called main methods. But usually someone specifies THE default entrypoint.